# How add a new property to Post entity in "WP REST API" plugin of WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to add a new property to the Post entity of "WP REST API" plugin. The new property is "views". It means the numbers of times that a post has been viewed. The data come from the plugin "Post Views Counter" how is on the WordPress table wp_post_views.

What's is the easiest form to do it?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

This is a very simple answer, using a wordpress plugin:

```
function get_viewed_count_post( $data, $post, $context ) {
  // We only want to modify the 'view' context, for reading posts
  if ( $context !== 'view' || is_wp_error( $data ) ) {
    return $data;
  }

  //Eliminate unused variables
  unset($data['author']);
  unset($data['terms']);
  unset($data['meta']);

  $viewed = db_select($data['ID']);

  if (!empty( $viewed )) {
    $data['post_viewed'] = $viewed;
  }

  return $data;
}

function db_select($id) {
    global $wpdb;

    $px_table_name = $wpdb->prefix.'post_views';

    $sql = "SELECT count FROM $px_table_name WHERE ID='$id' AND type = 4";

    return intval($wpdb->get_var($sql));
}

add_filter( 'json_prepare_post', 'get_viewed_count_post', 13, 3 );
```